# How safe is JSONP implementation for login functionality

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am using JSONP for login authentication, below is sample **JQuery Code:**

```
$.ajax({  
        type:"GET",        
        url: "https://staging/login/Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str, 
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        timeout: 200000,
        jsonp:"skywardDetails",
        success: function(result)
        { 
              //Do something after the success
        } 

    });
```

In above code, I am having **HTTPS** page for authentication, from my login dailog box, I am sending **username** and **password** to my login.aspx page, which calls **"WEB SERVICE"** taking input send by the login dialog page and return the users details as JSONP object.

My question is that, how **safe** is above implementation and do also suggest how can I improve my security implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly to authenticate a username/password, that is just as safe as submitting a login form to the same location. The security problem would come from what you're doing (or not doing) in the `success` function and future ajax requests as javascript can be forged/changed on the fly to tamper with variables (userid notably) you have set.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, but as you can see I am JSONP so we can't have POST in ajax request, I will be using "GET" only with above approach. In success I am just setting the details in my page, I mean the user details which is coming from server side, I am just displaying it in my page to "My Account" section. please suggest is it ok?

Comment: If you're only using it to retrieve some user details (name, location, etc), then this is fine, albeit annoying for the user since they'll have to login again on the next page reload since you aren't setting up a session. I suggest you use the authentication to set a session id, then use that to authenticate further requests.